# How React handles the event execution of two quick clicks of a button with a short interval？

Tags: reactjs

The React document(https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates) mentions a description of event handling when multiple clicks occur:***React does not batch across multiple intentional events like clicks—each click is handled separately. Rest assured that React only does batching when it’s generally safe to do. This ensures that, for example, if the first button click disables a form, the second click would not submit it again***.It means that React does not batch multiple click events, such as a button that triggers form submission. If you quickly click twice, the form will only be submitted once.

But considering such a special example(https://codesandbox.io/s/great-feather-wv3g2y?file=/src/App.js)：

```js
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
      {Array(99999)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, key) => (
          <p key={key}>{Math.random()}</p>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This React Component has a status called 'count', it will be shown on screen when rendered, then you can click the button to add the 'count', at last threre is a long dom list which in order to make 'React render' become a long javascript task.

If you quickly click the button twice, the page will experience a temporary lag, because the long task of javascript is running during that time. In my opinion, when you click the button the second time, a onClick callback will be added to a task queue waiting for excuting itself, but what is this onClick callback ? At this time, the real dom may not have completed the update (hence the long task of javascript), so i consider that **the onClick callback at the second time is same as the one on the first time**. so the value of 'count' in this onClick callback is still '0'. So I predicted that the screen would display '1' instead of '2'.

but the result is '2', not '1'.I think this result is in line with expectations, but I don't know how React achieved it, or what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

**I usually make a function that ignores the second event if it's short interval.**

This is the one of few things I've frustrated. It's kind of impossible to manage when the DOM updates every single second. I think there are few ways to prevent. I'd just like to share how I did it.

This is a code snippet of scroll event function which could be fired within very short period. I just wanted to ignore the second event. So save current time and compare the previous event time. I use `useRef` to prevent unnecessary rerender.

```js
const handleScroll = useCallback((e: UIEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const tick = 50; // 50ms
    const now = Date.now();

    if (now - nowRef.current < tick) return;
    nowRef.current = now;

    setScrollHeight(e.currentTarget.scrollTop);
  }, []);

  ...

  return (
    <div className="h-full overflow-y-auto" onScroll={handleScroll}>
      ...
    </div>
  );
```

So basically it will ignore if the scroll event have fired again within 50ms. And It doesn't have to be current time. It could be your loading state or something.

I think you can get the idea from the code. Hope this helps!

---

**Updated**

I think it's more like a Javascript thing not React. And you're right Javasciprt is a single thread so it can do only one job at a time. However, our browser is more than just runtime. The browsers do other things and has an event loop.

> JavaScript has a runtime model based on an event loop, which is
> responsible for executing the code, collecting and processing events,
> and executing queued sub-tasks.

[MDN Event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)

So the event loop makes never blocking. When you click the button for the first time, the click event goes to the queue and stack is empty Javascript executes your code which takes time. Then when you click the button for the second time this click event also goes to the queue. This time, however, stack is not empty so it will stay there until the stack is empty. When the first job is done, the second event will be passed to the stack and the Javascript engine will run the code.

So this is how browser never blocks user inputs and still be able to execute later, because it will be stored in the queue anyway.

This is the perfect explanation YouTube video about the event loop > [What the heck is the event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en)

---

**Second update**

> *is the click event triggered at the second time same as the one at the first time?*

**No it's not the same callback. Your state already has updated but the browser hasn't painted yet**

**Why?** Because every render has its own props in `React`

So when you click the for the first time, the state(count) has changed so `React` rerender(Flushing changes to the DOM) and let the browser paint the screen which takes quite a long time in your case. But even though it takes a long time it doesn't block your UI(in your case button). Technically, when you click the button for the second time quickly, `React` still updates your state and add to the queue.
Currently, the browser is painting the screen so it will wait until it's done. After the first state update painting it will do the same thing.
**The browser merges those two updates together and shows the latest updates for better UX. But if you add `console.log`, you can see it's rendered twice.**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log("rendered!", { count }); // rendered! {count: 1}, rendered! {count: 2}

  return (
...
```

These links could help

- https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/
- https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/

Comment: In my case, I think what React did was the right thing: if you clicked the button twice, the value of count should be '2'. But I don't know how React achieves this when a JavaScript long task is blocking main thread.I think in this situation, the callback function for two clicks is the same.

Comment: so what i really want to know is:  is the click event triggerd at the second time same as the one at the first time?

Comment: No, they are two different callbacks

Comment: you might consider a generic debounce hook for that scroll handler, or maybe better would be a hook around `requestAnimationFrame`